# Provide SOAP Interface with payara micro

Tags: soap, jax-ws, payara-micro

payara micro doesn't provide a JAX-WS stack out of the box. Does anyone know about a way to serve SOAP Interfaces with payara micro?

Answer (score 1):

Payara Micro doesn't provide SOAP functionality out of the box yet. The only option currently is to use a library that can help you, such as [Apache CXF](https://cxf.apache.org/) or [Metro](https://javaee.github.io/metro/). You can either bundle the library into your app or bundle it into a custom Payara Micro JAR with the `--addJars` and `--outputUberJar` options.

It's essentially the same thing you would need to do with plain servlet containers like Tomcat, Jetty; or with Java EE Web Profile-only containers like TomEE, because none of them contains the SOAP functionality out of the box.